# Tomcat Basic Authentication only in specific context path

Tags: tomcat, servlets, basic-authentication, web.xml

We are currently facing an issue while implementing basic authentication for a specific path inside a webapp context.

Our webapps have a mapped path defined in the context.xml (example: Context path="/test_web")

What we try to reach is that only the path above is secured via basic auth.

It is not possible to do it via the global web.xml (url pattern with /test_web/* does not match).

Comment: Please add in what you have tried in `web.xml`

Comment: @ST.Kee we have tried /* -> which protects all apps globally, we have tried /test_web/* , /test_web*

Comment: Why not edit your question and add in the related code snippet. When dealing with url mapping, you normally omit the application name, e.g. `http://<domain.com>/app/secure-resource`, you only do `/secure-resource` not `/app/secure-resource`